# Approximation of $f(x) = \max\left\{0,x\right\}$ using "dominate convergence theorem"

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f(x)$ be
$$
f(x) = \max\left\{0,x\right\}
$$

Which isn't differentiable in $x=0$, In order to approximate such function I'm using the sequence

$$
f_n(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} g_n(t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{1+e^{-nt}}dt = \frac{1}{n} \int_{-\infty}^{nx} \frac{1}{1+e^{-t}}dt = \frac{1}{n}\left(nx + \log(1+e^{-nx})\right) = \frac{1}{n}\log(1+e^{nx})
$$

And I want to prove that this is correct. In order to prove this I observe that

$$
g_n(x) \leq 1
$$

and that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(x) = u(x)
$$

where $u(x)$ is the step function. By the dominate convergence theorem I can then say that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{x} g_n(t) dt = \int_{-\infty}^{x} \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(t) dt = \int_{-\infty}^{x} u(t) dt = \max\left\{0,x\right\}
$$

I omitted the measurability of the sequence and $u$, but that's trivial right?

Is everything correct?

**Update**: I believe that since
$$
\forall n \; g_n(x) \leq u(x)
$$

the whole argument could work.

Comment: Why not $f(x) = 0$ for $x\leq 0$ and $f(x)=x$ for $x>0$?

Comment: @MrYouMath I don't get the comment, are you asking why I haven't used the explicit expression?

Comment: I am just asking why you are using such a complicated approximation if the function is pretty easy to express for $x\leq 0$ and $x>0$? Is this an exercise?

Comment: It's not differentiable, while the sequence is differentiable, so basically you have an expression like $f(\vec{x}) = \max \left\{0, g(\vec{x}) \right\}$ you can apply some optimization algorithms that require smooth functions (if $g$ is smooth enough). Also it's an exercise yes, the technique of approximating the function by starting with the derivative might be useful.

Comment: You can easily check that $$\frac{1}{n}(nx + \ln (1+ e^{-nx}))$$ converges to $\max \{ 0,x \}$, without the use of dominated convergence theorem. Anyway, you DCT does not apply here, since $1 \notin L^1(- \infty , x)$. But you can use monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Moreover, you can approximate more easily with $$f_n(x)=\ln (1+e^{nx})$$

Comment: @Crostul Why doesn't $1$ belong to $L^1(-\infty,x)$? Isn't the integral bounded? Also I don't see that hypothesis stated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem And your approximation doesn't seem to work to me https://www.desmos.com/calculator/h4it77i0tb

Comment: Sorrry, I meant $\ln (1+ e^{nx})/n$. Well, $$\int_{- \infty}^x 1 dx = \infty$$

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here... shouldn't it be first of all $$\int_{-\infty}^x 1 dt$$? What's the $1$ function? Your approximation is the same formula as mine, if in the argument I factor $e^{nx}$ I'd get the same formula.

Comment: You literally meant $1$... I didn't get that.. and $1$ is not integrable, this is why I cannot apply the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: If I distinguish anyway between $x < 0$ and $x \geq 0$ the DCT can be applied.

Comment: Hi, I wrote an update. Would now be fine?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you needed the integrals in your heuristic process leading to
$$f_n(x):={1\over n}\bigl( nx+\log(1+e^{-nx})\bigr)\ .$$
But now we can forget about them and just prove that for **fixed** $x$ one has
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=\max\{0,x\}\ .$$
This is easy. You have to distinguish the cases $x>0$, $x=0$, and $x<0$.

Comment: But is the proof correct? It might be twisted, but I still like it.